# Having a certain ID in the drop down list always at the bottom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a subject dropdownlist for a contact form. I always want the Other to be at the bottom of the list. The reason I ask this is because I created a controller so if I wanted to add more subjects I could do so.  Anyways suggestions or ways I could go about making sure that the position of the Other subject is always on the bottom of the list?

```
public void PrepareSubjectCombo()
        {
            // Grab a list of subjects for the dialog box
            IRepository<Subject> subjectRepository = new Repository<Subject>();
            List<Subject> subjects = subjectRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Position).ToList();
            subjects.Insert(0, new Subject() { ID = 0, Name = "- Please Select -" });
            ViewData["Subjects"] = subjects;
        }
```

I have posted my combo box if this is of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use the proper overload of the DropDownList helper when rendering your dropdown in the view instead of trying to insert some dummy items into the collection:

```
public void PrepareSubjectCombo()
{
    // Grab a list of subjects for the dialog box
    IRepository<Subject> subjectRepository = new Repository<Subject>();
    List<Subject> subjects = subjectRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Position).ToList();
    ViewData["Subjects"] = subjects;
}
```

and then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "selectedSubject", 
    new SelectList(ViewData["Subjects"] as List<Subject>, "ID", "Name"), 
    "- Please Select -"
)
```

---

Now this being said, everytime I see someone using ViewData/ViewBag/ViewCrap instead of strongly typed views and view models I get sick and I feel myself into the obligation to show the correct way of doing this.

As always you start with a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedSubject { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

then you have a controller action which will take care of populating this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // TODO: You definitively don't want to hardcode your repository like this
    // but use a constructor injection or this action will be impossible to unit test
    IRepository<Subject> subjectRepository = new Repository<Subject>();
    var subjects = subjectRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Position).ToList();
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Subjects = subjects.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.ID.ToString(),
            Text = x.Name
        })
    };   
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedSubject, 
    new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Value", "Text"), 
    "- Please Select -"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = YourDataSource;
DropDownList1.DataBind();

//Insert Other subject to the end
ListItem litem = new ListItem(" Other subject ", "value");
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(DropDownList1.Items.Count, litem);
```

Comment: -1. The OP is asking about ASP.NET MVC. What you have shown has nothing to do with MVC. It is standard WebForms code. You are showing some datasources, databindings, server side controls, etc... all things that doesn't exist in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code as shown below:

```
public void PrepareSubjectCombo()
{
    // Grab a list of subjects for the dialog box
    IRepository<Subject> subjectRepository = new Repository<Subject>();
    List<Subject> subjects = subjectRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(t => t.Position).ToList();
    subjects.Insert(0, new Subject() { ID = 0, Name = "- Please Select -" });
    // Add this line
    // Make sure you use the correct ID for the "Other" subject
    subjects.Add(new Subject() { ID = 100, Name = "Other" });
    // If you determine the ID based on the list, simply set the ID = subjects.Count + 1
    int otherID = subjects.Count + 1;
    subjects.Add(new Subject() { ID = otherID, Name = "Other" });
    ViewData["Subjects"] = subjects;
}
```